# Prevent parent object from saving if even one but not all child objects are valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

When submitting a form_for for a parent model object that has many children, if just one child is valid, the parent still save.

I want to prevent parent object from saving if just one child is invalid.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :units
  validates_associated :units
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
  validates_numericality_of :quantity, :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
end
```

When I have many units in an order, if there is a unit.quantity > 0, the order record persists, along with those units that validate.

Comment: Can you add the code of your current models?

Comment: Yes of course... see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to spread the gospel of [Why You Don’t Need Has_and_belongs_to_many Relationships](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/) as often as I can. Try the following setup:

Models

```
# Order model
has_many :order_units
has_many :units, through: :order_units
accepts_nested_attributes_for :units
validates_associated :units

# Unit model
has_many :order_units
has_many :orders, through: :order_units
validates_numericality_of :quantity, only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, allow_blank: true

# OrderUnit model
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :unit
```

Controller

```
# OrdersController, new and edit actions
3.times do
    @order.units.build
end

# white listed params
def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(units_attributes: [:id, :quantity, :_destroy])
end
```

Form View

```
# Order _form partial
<%= f.fields_for :units do |unit| -%>
    <%= content_tag :p, unit.text_field(:quantity) %>
<% end %>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. This was the solution i ended up using. has_many through was much easier.

Comment: @MarkDRubyist, could you please mark this as the answer to close it out.